# How do I start a powershell process with administrator privilges and redirect stdin (os.exec)

Tags: windows, powershell, go, uac

I want to start a powershell process with administrator priviliges and redirect stdin to a writer, I have everything working except how to run it as admin.

```golang
// Start powershell
powershell := exec.Command("powershell")
// Add something that will open UAC and give the process admin priviliges

powershell.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
powershell.Env = os.Environ()

// Create pipe to write to it later
stdin, err := powershell.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer stdin.Close()
```

As it seems there is no such thing as `Process.Verb` that I can set to "runas", I tried creating a powershell process by using powershell commands `Start-Process ... -Verb runas` and got the pid of the process successfully, but it seems like there's no way to manipulate stdin and stdout later with a pid.

Comment: This approach cannot work anyway -- non-elevated processes piping to elevated ones would be a security hole, so this is simply not allowed. What you can do is write the commands to execute to a script file and have your elevated instance execute that.

Comment: I see, what if I give my golang executeable administrator permissions, would that work?

Comment: Yes, if the process itself is elevated (either through user action or because it's requested through a manifest) its children will be elevated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jeroen-mostert I kinda figured it out. I started my go executeable as admin and used `StartProcess powershell.exe -verb RunAs`, it isn't working like I wanted in the beginning, but at least it doesnt open UAC for powershell anymore.